# SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS / FOUND_ROWS() does not work in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in Mysql SELECT statement, to get the number of lines my SELECT would return without a LIMIT clause.

```
$sql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '');
$sql->select_db('mysql');
$s1 = $sql->query('select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from db limit 0, 3');
$s2 = $sql->query('select FOUND_ROWS()');
if($row = $s2->fetch_row()) printf('%d/%d', $s1->num_rows, $row[0]);
```

On my WinXP dev station it return 3/0 everytime for several weeks. When I use another MySQL server from my station it return 3/0 too. 
On anothers PC the same code runs fine, and return the correct number (3/17 for example, if I have 17 records in mysql.db table). Every XP PC have the same PHP/Mysql version, and it ran fine in the past on my PC
Using Mysql Query Browser with the same SQL queries I get the right number.

Could anyone give me an idea of solution, without re-install all?

Sorry, my previous request was awfully unclear.

Comment: Can you include your PHP code? Are you definitely asking for the count using the same database connection resource as the one used for the query?

Comment: Your question lacks the error that's produced and the code you are using, thumbs down.

Comment: @PaulDixon Thanks Paul! In our .net code, we are always creating new connections so as soon as I read your comment, I knew that must be my problem.

Comment: @JasonFuller - might want to sort that out. A new connection for every single query is awfully expensive.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thank you.

When I ran something analogous to your example on the mysql command line, it would work; but running it from php, it failed. The second query has to "know about" the first one, so I figure somehow that persistence/memory linking the two queries was getting messed up by the php.

(It turns out that Wordpress uses this type of query to do its pagination - so our larger problem was that the pagination in a wordpress install suddenly stopped working when we moved to php 5.2.6 ... eventually tracked it down to the FOUND_ROWS()).

Just for the sake of posting for people who may run into this in the future... for me it was the php setting "mysql.trace_mode" - this defaulted "on" in 5.2.6 instead of "off" like previously, and for some reason prevents the FOUND_ROWS() from working.

As a "fix", we could either put this in every php page (actually, in a common "include"):

```
ini_set("mysql.trace_mode", "0");
```

or add this to the .htaccess:

```
php_value mysql.trace_mode "0"
```

Thanks again,
Jerry

Answer (score 10):

Are you using a MySQL query method that allows for multiple queries.

From MySQL documentation.

> To obtain this row count, include a `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in the SELECT  statement, and then invoke `FOUND_ROWS()` afterward

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Also just for fun, there's a great discussion about the race condition of `FOUND_ROWS()`'s usage [here.](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php#85654)

Comment: The race condition is to be expected, but I would suspect not really that important for an operation such as this. Even so, good to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to use mysqli_multi_query as stated in the PHP manual by passing both queries containing SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS separated with a semicolon

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM db limit 0, 3;";
$query .= "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";

/* execute multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: I think it has to be SELECT FOUND_ROWS()

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution is to subquery your actual query like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM (SELECT whatever FROM whatever WHERE whatever LIMIT whatever) ax; 
select FOUND_ROWS();
```

Now you will get the correct results. I think the main reason being that `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` mainly tracks rows found (i.e. without `LIMITS`) not rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The solution was stupid, I was using `$wpdb->query` instead of `$wpdb->get_var`. So you want to do

```
$wpdb->get_var('select FOUND_ROWS()');
```

if you're on WordPress

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was a problem with mysql php extension bundled with php 5.2.6. Mysqli run fine, and another php version too.
Sorry for noise and unclear question.

If you have the same problem, my advice is to re-install PHP or change version.