# Django: How to count a queryset and return a slice without hitting DB twice?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have this part of the code in my API which recently has become a somewhat bottleneck:

```
total = results.count()
if request.GET.has_key('offset'):
    offset = int(request.GET.get('offset').strip())
    results = results.order_by('name')[100*offset:100*(offset+1)]
people = list(results)
```

Note that `results` is the queryset of all the people and `offset` is a param used for pagination. 
 
 Here I can see, when I print [`connection.queries`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running), that my database getting hit twice by `.count()` and `list(results)`. The reason why `.count()` has to be at the top because I need to the length of all the people (Not 100.) Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Where exactly are you using `total`?

Comment: [MySQL can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2439870/1248008), but I don’t know how to make use of that using django and I am not sure whether other databases support this.

Comment: @JonasWielicki It's debatable whether this will even speed up things much; see: https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/ – a better way to address the issue here might be to first understand why those queries are taking too long. Appropriate indices can get you a long way.

Comment: OP, have you benchmarked why those queries are taking too long? Trying to make one query when you need two might seem like the obvious solution, but that doesn't mean it's the only (or even the best) one. **When doing performance optimization you should trust benchmarks first, not intuition.**

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Thanks for the pointer. Haven’t been doing any performance critical DB stuff in years.

Comment: @Jkdc: `total` is included in the response.

Comment: Going off of what @ThomasOrozco said,  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/optimization/#don-t-order-results-if-you-don-t-care - TLDR: add an index to the `name` if you will be using it for `order_by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?:

```
allpeople = list(results.order_by('name'))
total = len(allpeople)
if request.GET.has_key('offset'):
    offset = int(request.GET.get('offset').strip())
    results = allpeople[100*offset:100*(offset+1)]
people = results
```

Keep in mind that with `people = results` is going to fail if `if request.GET....:` doesn't fire.

Comment: You could initialize results like `results = allpeople = list(results...` in your first line to remove the need for your final caveat.

Comment: I disagree with this answer because we do not know the number of results that are being returned. Wrapping a QuerySet in `list()` causes it to be evaluated, and brings all results into memory. If you have several million results, this can be catastrophic. This happened to me recently, so I am speaking from experience.

Comment: You're correct. This is in fact slower as I did benchmark with million records. However, it totally answers the question of avoiding to hit the DB twice... Turned out @ThomasOrozco was right that fewer queries may not always be faster. Btw, the `name` index has always been there since the beginning.