# FOUND_ROWS() Fails in PHP

Tags: php

I need to retrieve the  total count of records after executing a query. I tried like this

```
<?php
include_once 'common.php';

ini_set("mysql.trace_mode", "Off");

$sql ="get_list(0, 40, 'Name', 'DESC', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)";

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

mysqli_select_db( $con, "crash_table");

mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$sql2= "SELECT FOUND_ROWS();";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

$count = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo "Count=".$count[0];

?>
```

but the count is always 0. In the code get_list() is a procedure where 40 is the LIMIT.. Why is it so?

Comment: The ; at the end of the SQL statement messing it up?

Comment: @Ted: No. ; is optional but not restricted

Comment: That is not the problem.. I chaged that..

Comment: Exact duplicate of [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS / FOUND_ROWS() does not work in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674061/sql-calc-found-rows-found-rows-does-not-work-in-php)

Comment: I tried all those ...But nops.

Answer (score 1):

Is `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` the last statement in you stored procedure? 
Because manual says:

> The row count available through FOUND_ROWS() is transient and not
>   intended to be available past the statement following the SELECT
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS statement.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS [ FIELDS NAME ] FROM [ TABLE NAME ] WHERE ........ [ORDER BY] LIMIT [ X,Y ];

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using mysql_num_rows() to retrieve the number of entries.