# How to count all records but only retrieve (LIMIT) a specific number for display?

Tags: mysql, pagination

I want to echo only the first 10 rows, but I need to count the total number of rows affected by the query.

I was doing a `LIMIT 10` and then counting with the obvious problem I kept getting 10 as the count.

What would be a proper way to do it?

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Badges WHERE UID = '$user' ORDER by Date DESC");
$count = mysql_num_rows($data);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    { 
    echo $row['Site'];
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count all rows when using SELECT with LIMIT in MySQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439829/how-to-count-all-rows-when-using-select-with-limit-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL has some special support for this sort of thing. First, include `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in your SELECT:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM Badges
WHERE UID = '$user'
ORDER by Date DESC
LIMIT 10 -- Or whatever
```

Then pull out your rows and then immediately look at [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) like this:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

to get the number of rows that matched your original query without considering the LIMIT clause.

This is MySQL-specific but it should be a little faster than doing two queries.

Comment: Seems you also need to disable `mysql.trace_mode` in config if it defaults to "On" in your version of PHP. Also, it's still two queries :)

Comment: Great! [Here it is...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

Comment: @Phil: So `mysql.trace_mode` sometimes causes queries behind your back that would mess up the `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`? I tend to be more of a Ruby/PostgreSQL guy than a PHP/MySQL guy.

Comment: @muistooshort Something like that, I've never used it. More of an ANSI SQL guy myself :) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674061/sql-calc-found-rows-found-rows-does-not-work-in-php/869957#869957

Comment: Thanks, this is how the code looked in the end in case someone finds it a useful reference:
`$data = mysql_query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM Badges LIMIT 10");
$count = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"));
echo $count[0]
`

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty standard to issue two queries, one selecting the desired columns with the limit clause and another selecting only a count with no limit.

For example

```
$countQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Badges WHERE UID = ?';
$limitQuery = 'SELECT * FROM Badges WHERE UID = ? ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 0, 10';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make 2 queries: the first one will count all rows, the second one will return 10 rows:

```
$count = 0;
$query = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM Badges WHERE UID = '$user'";
$rs = mysql_query($query);   

if (mysql_errno() == 0)
{
    $r = mysql_fetch_object($rs);
    $count = $r->count;
}

if ($count > 0)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Badges WHERE UID = '$user' ORDER by Date DESC LIMIT 10";
    $rs = mysql_query($query);      

    if (mysql_errno() == 0)
    {            
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs))       
        {       
            echo $r['Site']; 
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

count all records

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Badges WHERE UID = '$user' ORDER by Date DESC");
$count = mysql_num_rows($data);
echo "No of Records is :" . $count;
```

print 10 records...

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Badges WHERE UID = '$user' ORDER by Date DESC LIMIT 0, 10");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
        { 
        echo $row['Site'];
        }
```

Comment: I'm guessing you got a -1 for proposing a `SELECT *` to perform a count operation (with an `ORDER BY` clause, no less!) when `SELECT COUNT(*)` is MUCH faster (and the "correct" way to do it).