# PDO PHP & MYSQL SELECT FOUND_ROWS() always returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Good day, I've been trying to figure out a problem in my code. I'm using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() to retrieve the total amount of records in my database (with PDO). My problem is that FOUND_ROWS() always returns 0.

The thing is that I got it working before, but I made some adjustments here and there and now it stopped working. I can't for the love of me remember what I could have deleted that was important and can't seem to find any good documentation using these functions with PDO.

So far I've tried putting it in different loops, tried fetch() with different modes, tried placing the commands in different order (i.e. before the while and after the while loop etc.). I think I'm just missing something very easy here, but I've been staring it this thing for about 1 or 2 hours now and it's driving me mad.

So here's my code:

```
public function findBerichten($args)
{       
    //$offset zorg ervoor dat pagina 1 als record 0 in de database zoekt
    $offset = ($args['huidigePagina'] - 1) * $args['itemsPerPagina'];

    $sth = $this->db->DBH()->prepare("SELECT    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
                                                berichten.berichtID, 
                                                berichten.bericht, 
                                                berichten.naam, 
                                                berichten.mail
                                        FROM    `berichten` 
                                        ORDER BY berichten.datumToegevoegd DESC 
                                        LIMIT   ?, ?");
    $sth->bindParam(1, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $args['itemsPerPagina'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $berichten = array();

    while($row = $sth->fetch())
    {
        $bericht = new Bericht();
        $bericht->setBerichtID(htmlentities(strip_tags($row['berichtID'])));
        $bericht->setBericht(htmlentities(strip_tags($row['bericht'])));
        $bericht->setNaam(htmlentities(strip_tags($row['naam'])));
        $bericht->setMail(htmlentities(strip_tags($row['mail'])));  
        $berichten[] = $bericht; 
    }

    $sth = $this->db->DBH()->prepare("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as aantalBerichten");
    $sth->execute();
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->aantalBerichten = $sth->fetch();

    var_dump($this->aantalBerichten);

    return $berichten;
}
```

index.php

```
if($huidigePagina < 1)
{
    //$huidigePagina is 1
    $huidigePagina = 1;
}

//Als de huidige pagina groter is als het totaal aantal pagina's
if($huidigePagina > $totaalPaginas)
{
    //$huidigePagina is gelijk aan het totaal aantal pagina's
    $huidigePagina = $totaalPaginas;
}

$berichtDAO->findBerichten(array('huidigePagina'=>$huidigePagina, 'itemsPerPagina'=>10))
```

output var_dump: `array(1) { ["aantalBerichten"]=> string(1) "0" }`

If you've got any idea's let me know because I'm willing to try just about anything right now :)
Here's to hoping this question isn't too noob! As I said, I think I'm missing something very easy here.

**edit**
the execute() function is correct etc. when used in if() statement it still proceeds to execute code

Also; im 90% sure this has got to do with the FOUND_ROWS() portion of code.

**edit 2, included db class and Bericht() class**
Bericht class:

```
<?php 

Class Bericht
{
    private $db;
    private $berichtID;
    private $bericht;
    private $naam;
    private $mail;

    public function __construct(Db $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function setBerichtID($berichtID)
    {
        $this->berichtID = $berichtID;
    }

    public function getBerichtID()
    {
        return $this->berichtID;
    }

    public function setBericht($bericht)
    {
        $this->bericht = $bericht;
    }

    public function getBericht()
    {
        return $this->bericht;
    }

    public function setNaam($naam)
    {
        $this->naam = $naam;
    }

    public function getNaam()
    {
        return $this->naam;
    }

    public function setMail($mail)
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;
    }

    public function getMail()
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }
}
```

db class:

```
<?php
class Db
{
    //bij het laden van Db
    public function __construct()
    {
        //voer functie connect() uit
        $this->connect();
    }

    //functie voor het verbinding maken met en het selecteren van een database
    private function connect()
    {
        //$connection is connectie naar mysql database (met de opgegeven inlog waardes)
        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pw');

        //als er geen connectie gemaakt kan worden
        if(!$connection)
        {
            //die (voer overige code niet meer uit) en echo string + de mysql error
            die("Kan geen verbinding maken: " . mysql_error());
        }

        //selecteert de opgegeven database met de connectie ($connection)
        mysql_select_db("db", $connection);
    }

    public function DBH()
    {
        try 
        {
            $DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'pw');
            $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $DBH;
        }

        catch (PDOException $except)
        {
            echo $except->getMessage();
        }
    }

    //function to retrieve records -- not important
    public function getRecords($sth)
    {
        $rows = array();

        if($sth->execute() == true)
        {       
            $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            while($row = $sth->fetch())
            {
                $rows[] = $row;
            }

            return $rows;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest - does the construct for the Bericht class do any sql queries?

Comment: @ChrisK No it does not, all the Bericht class contains are setters & getters

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Or is it just 0? Have you tried looping through the recordsets using `nextRowset()`?

Comment: Not receiving any errors, it's just returning 0. Haven't tried looping trough the recordsets using nextRowset(), I'll go ahead and try that now.

Comment: @Bono You basically need to completely debug it, you are probably right about it being very simple but the easiest way to find it is by debugging it. **Have you tried executing the code from mysql?**

Comment: Just had a thought, does $this->db->DBH() create a new sql session? (you havent included your db class so not sure)

Comment: @BenCarey code does the exact same thing in mysql.. Thanks for the advice though, I'm afraid I'm going to have to do some digging :/

Comment: @ChrisK I'll update my post with the db class and Bericht class; Though you could be right, I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with that? But as I said, will try anything

Comment: See answer below if that fixes it - you said you'd try anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not completely sure what is happening inside your DB class, so a few assumptions on this answer.

I assume this *was* working at one stage on your machine similar code, so trace_mode isnt the answer.

I assume

```
$this->db->DBH()
```

is a function which is going off to get a new database handler for use in the database query.

The second time you call the prepare function for DBH it is creating a new database handler which is not storing the information from the other DBH call earlier.

A fix would be to do something like

```
$dbh = $this->db->DBH();
```

early in the function, then replace the prepare calls with with

```
$dbh->prepare("(SQL)");
```

Edit: Looks like at least my DB->DBH() assumption was correct!

Comment: I think this may be the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the MySQL trace mode in PHP?

In PHP 5.2.6, this defaults to On and can cause some errors with `FOUND_ROWS()`

You can do this using one of three methods:

**php.ini:**

```
mysql.trace_mode = 0
```

**PHP:**

```
ini_set("mysql.trace_mode", "0");
```

**.htaccess:**

```
php_value mysql.trace_mode "0"
```

**Alternatively:**

I am not sure whether the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` is being passed to the second PDO session. Have you tried combining them into one query and retrieving multiple recordsets? It is very easy to do

Comment: Nope, trace_mode is not the problem, allready looked into it as well :P still tried, what you suggested with ini_set and didn't change anything.. I'll try combining them into one query later! cheers

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a comma behind SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in your SQL

Comment: No, that's not the problem, it's not supposed to have a comma there (allready checked that myself too ;))

Comment: Apparently the mysql trace mode may have something to do with your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674061/sql-calc-found-rows-found-rows-does-not-work-in-php

Comment: Aye, but again, this is not the case ;( Thanks for the help though, much appreciated!