# SELECT FOUND_ROWS() return 1 in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

SELECT FOUND_ROWS() not working or return 1 i dont know where i do mistake

```
$qry ="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT user_id, login_date
FROM login_members
WHERE (login_date BETWEEN '2012-02-13 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-13 23:59:59') 
LIMIT 0, 10";

$rs = mysql_query($qry);

$total_records = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"),0,0);
```

Comment: you want to know total records ?

Comment: sir this is not my solution plz suggest best one forget old/new etc

Comment: yes Devang Rathod but by using select found rows

Comment: possible duplicate issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674061/sql-calc-found-rows-found-rows-does-not-work-in-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this query

```
$qry ="SELECT DISTINCT user_id, login_date
FROM login_members
WHERE (login_date BETWEEN '2012-02-13 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-13 23:59:59') 
LIMIT 0, 10";
```

if the preceding SELECT contain SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, but if the preceding SELECT doesn't contain SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, FOUND_ROWS() return the number of rows returned by this preceding SELECT

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer seems to be wrong. as it suggest an use of found_rows() after a query with LIMIT in it.

**ANSWER**: The question is about the RETURN 1 and in some case 0 as a result of found_rows();

it happens when some other query is exectued after your first select statment. 
especially when you are using an IDE or some client to run your queries, some additiona 'preparational' queries are executed before and after your query.

and found_rows() will return the numer of result returned by the LAST query run on the server. which in this case is not the one we are expecting.

and hence the RETURN 1 or 0 error.

**Verification:**
You can verify this by enabling general logging on your server, and executing the queries. 
you will see couple of additonal queries exectued between 'the first query and the found row query'.

**FIX**
stored procedure, or the ver old COUNT(*).

performance wise there is hardly any difference.

**ADDITIONAL**

if your object is to find the total number of rows returned then it's fine. 
and the use of   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS becomes immaterial.

here is a general rule, LIMIT is not required for found rows, nor  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. 
But three of them can be used together to give a very useful result.

ie on running something like.

```
SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from some_table_name LIMIT 0,10; 
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

We will get the number of rows that would have been returned by the query had we run 
SELECT * from sometable_name; 
ie: without the LIMIT.

having said that,

```
SELECT * from some_table_name LIMIT 0, 10; 
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

would give us the total number of results which cos of the limit will be <=10. and doesn't server any practical purpose, but it's NOT an error.

Comment: I would like to give my thanks here. It fixed my critical problem. I was running `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST` before every query, to detect if base-query is too slow..  it would record, what queries were running before it. This however, kills the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`. Thanks again, seemed like a impossible thing to debug at first!

Answer (score 8):

A `SELECT` statement may include a `LIMIT` clause to restrict the number of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned without the LIMIT, but without running the statement again. To obtain this row count, include a `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in the `SELECT` statement, and then invoke `FOUND_ROWS()` afterward:

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;

mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The second `SELECT` returns a number indicating how many rows the first `SELECT` would have returned had it been written without the `LIMIT` clause.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: if this post help u please mark as a answer to help other viewers.

Answer (score 0):

should be :

```
$qry ="SELECT DISTINCT user_id, login_date FROM login_members
WHERE (login_date BETWEEN '2012-02-13 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-13 23:59:59') 
LIMIT 0, 10";

$rs = mysql_query($qry);

$total_records = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"),0,0);

echo $total_records // display total record count
```

There is no need to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`

Answer (score 0):

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `FOUND_ROWS()` can be useful in situations when you want to restrict the number of rows that a query returns, but also determine the number of rows in the full result set without running the query again. An example is a Web script that presents a paged display containing links to the pages that show other sections of a search result. Using `FOUND_ROWS()` allows you to determine how many other pages are needed for the rest of the result.

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The second `SELECT` returns a number indicating how many rows the first `SELECT` 
would have returned had it been written without the `LIMIT` clause. 
In the absence of the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`  option in the most recent successful 
`SELECT` statement, `FOUND_ROWS()` returns the number of rows in the result set 
returned by that statement. If the statement includes a `LIMIT` clause, `FOUND_ROWS()`
returns the number of rows up to the limit. For example, `FOUND_ROWS()` returns 10 
or 60, respectively, if the statement includes `LIMIT 10` or `LIMIT 50, 10`.

```
$qry ="SELECT SQL_CAL_FOUND_ROWS  *  
       FROM login_members
       WHERE (login_date BETWEEN '2012-02-13 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-13 23: 
59:59') 
       LIMIT 0, 10";

$rs = mysql_query($qry);

$total_records = mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as `found_rows`;");

echo $total_records // display total record count
```

Answer (score 0):

For total records use simple:

```
 $total_records = array_shift(mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set mysql.trace_mode to off.

Use this is in each php page.

```
ini_set("mysql.trace_mode", "0");
```

or you can set this on .htaccess file

```
php_value mysql.trace_mode "0"
```

Here:

```
<?php
ini_set("mysql.trace_mode", "0");

$qry ="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT user_id, login_date
FROM login_members
WHERE (login_date BETWEEN '2012-02-13 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-13 23:59:59') 
LIMIT 0, 10";

$rs = mysql_query($qry);

$total_records = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"),0,0);
echo $total_records;
?>
```