# mysql row count fail

Tags: mysql, sql, rows, calc

I'm currently using SQL_calc_found_rows on a pagination page. On my local and it returns the row count as expected based on the SQL query perfectly..... We then run it on our staging, and test servers all is perfectly fine... Results of the returned row count is correct and as expected.
However when run on our live machines the row count is wrong and always the same value. I'm totally lost and perplexed. Any help on this? Guidance?

Comment: are you using php? than this can help maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674061/sql-calc-found-rows-found-rows-does-not-work-in-php

Comment: I did see this question/answer before and unfortunately every option/opinion we tried did not help unfortunately... Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Incidently the version of mysql server where we are having this issues is version 5.6.10 ...... This a very active production machine so upgrading and down grading machine version on the fly is almost beyond whimsical reach at this point.