# How can I use COALESCE() on FOUND_ROWS()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my code:

```
$msg_num = $this->dbh->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()')->fetchColumn();
```

Sometimes `$msg_num` is empty. Now I want to put `0` in it when it is empty. So here is my new code:

```
$msg_num = $this->dbh->query('SELECT COALESCE(FOUND_ROWS(),0)')->fetchColumn();
```

But still it is empty. What's wrong and how can I do that?

---

Noted that I can do that using PHP like this:

```
.
.
if ( empty($msg_num) ){
    $msg_num = 0;
}
```

But I want to know how can I do that in the SQL layer.

Comment: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS f UNION SELECT 0 ORDER BY f DESC LIMIT 1;`?

Comment: I think something else is wrong. `FOUND_ROWS()` should return `0` if none are found.  I suspect your query is returning an error.

Comment: "But still it is empty. What's wrong and how can I do that?" -> `FOUND_ROWS()` depends of running `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ...` first.. Are you doing this?

Comment: Besides `SELECT COALESCE(FOUND_ROWS(),0)` is wierd because `COALESCE` returns the first non NULL value which in this case is always `FOUND_ROWS()` because `FOUND_ROWS()` always returns INT 0 or higher

Comment: You might find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674061/sql-calc-found-rows-found-rows-does-not-work-in-php)